# When fetching JSON and inputting the data into variable, it gives me undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using the Advice Slip API. As the title says, when I input the JSON data into the variable, like this:

```js
 let advi;
fetch("https://api.adviceslip.com/advice").then(r => r.json()).then(adv => advi = adv);
```

It gives me the error that I mentioned. However, when I replace
`.then(adv => advi = adv)`
with
`.then(console.log)`
it gives me an object with the advice. However, since I don't want to just console.log the advice as I need to use it in my website, I need to find a way to use it in a variable.

Comment: this link is now working, when I am trying to fetch this link on postman.

Comment: I think you need the authorization to fetch this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.js**

```js
function showData() {
let advi;
fetch("https://api.adviceslip.com/advice").then(r => r.json()).then(adv => {
    advi = adv;
    console.log(advi);
  })
}

showData();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Actually, the implementation wasn't working, you have to declare it as a global variable using `window.advi = adv`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to iterate `advi` just below call `fetch` api, yes the `advi` variable is still undefined, because fetch is Web API which is asynchronous.